# Unix: Modify a line in a file only if it is preceded by a particular line

Tags: shell, awk, sed, scripting

I have a text file that looks like this -

```
Random text
Some more random text ...

TEXT_CATEGORY_A(
    SOME_INFO, A,
    "Some random text.",
    "Other info.",
    )
TEXT_CATEGORY_B(
    SOME_INFO, B,
    "Some random text.",
    "Other info.",
    )
TEXT_CATEGORY_C(
    SOME_INFO, C,
    "Some random text.",
    "Other info.",
    )
```

and so on ...
I want to remove comma from the last sentence of each TEXT_CATEGORY container i.e. from -

```
"Other info.",
```

So the final form of the file should look like this -

```
Random text
Some more random text ...

TEXT_CATEGORY_A(
    SOME_INFO, A,
    "Some random text.",
    "Other info."
    )
TEXT_CATEGORY_B(
    SOME_INFO, B,
    "Some random text.",
    "Other info."
    )
TEXT_CATEGORY_C(
    SOME_INFO, C,
    "Some random text.",
    "Other info."
    )
```

If I can somehow find out that the next line contains only the `)` character then I can solve this problem.
I cannot solve this problem using sed as it reads the file line by line. Is there some way that I can find out about contents of the next line or is there some other way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved using sed as follows -

```
sed -E '/,$/N; s/",$/"/' file
```

This is a slight modification to the solution provided by @RomanPerekhrest.

Answer (score 2):

Flexibly with `sed` command:

```
sed -E '/,$/N; s/([^,]+),\s+\)$/\1\n)/' file
```

- `/,$/` - match line that ends with `,`
- `N` - capture next line into buffer space
- `\1` - the 1st captured group (points to `([^,]+)`)

The output:

```
Random text
Some more random text ...

TEXT_CATEGORY_A(
    SOME_INFO, A,
    "Some random text.",
    "Other info."
)
TEXT_CATEGORY_B(
    SOME_INFO, B,
    "Some random text.",
    "Other info."
)
TEXT_CATEGORY_C(
    SOME_INFO, C,
    "Some random text.",
    "Other info."
)
```

Comment: Hi @RomanPerekhrest, I tried your solution and somehow it does not modify anything. I modified the script a little like this - ` sed -E '/,$/N; s/",$/"/' file ` and then it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following. Using `tac` + `awk` here. This should be faster.

```
tac Input_file | awk '{sub(/,/,"")} 1' | tac
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
tac Input_file    ##Using tac to print Input_file inn reverse order.
awk '{            ##Using tac command output to awk program from here.
  sub(/,/,"")     ##Using sub to substitute very first occurrence of comma with NULL here.
}                 ##Closing BLOCK here.
1                 ##Mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited line here.
' | tac           ##Passing previous awk command output to tac command now and making it in its normal form.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS="" '
match($0,/.*,/){
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk -v RS="" '                                                    ##Starting awk program from here and setting RS(record separator) as NULL here.
match($0,/.*,/){                                                  ##Using match function of awk to match a regex till last occurrence of comma.
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)     ##Printing substring from RSTART to till value of RLENGTH-1 then again mentioning substrnig from RSTART+RLENGTH to till end of Input_file.
}                                                                 ##Closing BLOCK for match condition here.
'  Input_file                                                       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: @anubhava, Thank you sir. Since I don't have non GNU `awk` couldn't say it, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 The first solution is removing the comma from each line. The second solution is removing the comma only from the last "Other info." ie from the one belonging to TEXT_CATEGORY_C

Comment: @Harshu, both worked fine for me, could you please check once if you have control M characters in your Input_file by doing `cat -v Input_file` once?